# Encontrar índice de um valor em uma matriz

Tags: c#, matriz

Estou querendo procurar o índice de uma matriz por um valor:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Leão", "Guepardo", "Elefante" };
String[] array = new String[3] { "Leão", "Guepardo", "Elefante" };
```

Por exemplo, eu quero procurar o índice do valor "Elefante", como posso fazer isso? Tem algum método?, o `linq` é capaz de fazer essa busca e me retornar um índice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o *array* tem isso:

```
Array.IndexOf(array, "Elefante")
```

Para lista é:

```
list.IndexOf("Elefante")
```

Exemplo:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var list = new List<string>() { "Leão", "Guepardo", "Elefante" };
        var array = new string[3] { "Leão", "Guepardo", "Elefante" };
        WriteLine(list.IndexOf("Elefante"));
        WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(array, "Elefante"));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OHRCz5). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q3oaac). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/IndexOf.cs).

Answer (score 2):

## [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Pesquisa o objeto especificado e retorna o índice baseado em zero da
>   primeira ocorrência dentro de todo o List

```
 list.IndexOf("Elefante")
```

## [Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Pesquisa o objeto especificado e retorna o índice da primeira
>   ocorrência em uma matriz unidimensional.

```
Array.IndexOf(array, "Elefante")
```

<sup>[***Funcionando em dot.net fiddle***](http://%22A%20posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20em%20que%20o%20elefante%20se%20encontra%20%C3%A9%20%7B0%7D%22)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Penso que isto pode resolver o seu problema:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(a => a == "Elefante");
```

Faz uma pesquisa linear para obter o índice.